# Cursor en PL/SQL siempre devuelve FALSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

resulta que al usar `cursor%NOTFOUND` aunque la consulta dentro devuelva 0 filas, sigue devolviendo False.

Dejo aquí mi bloque:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BLOQUE_EXTRACTO(dnis CLIENTES_EXAMEN.DNI%type, 
num_tarj TARJETAS_EXAMEN.NUM%type, dias NUMBER)
AS
    v_DNI CLIENTES_EXAMEN.DNI%type;
    fechaF DATE;
    CURSOR cursorDNI IS
    SELECT C.DNI INTO v_DNI
    FROM CLIENTES_EXAMEN C, TARJETAS_EXAMEN  T
    WHERE C.DNI = T.DNI AND T.NUM = num_tarj AND T.DNI = dnis;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursorDNI;
    IF cursorDNI%NOTFOUND
    THEN
        RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
    ELSE
        fechaF := SYSDATE - dias;
        FOR filas IN (SELECT * FROM COMPRAS_EXAMEN WHERE NUM_TARJETA = num_tarj 
                  AND FECHA BETWEEN fechaF AND SYSDATE)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(filas.NUMC || ' ' || filas.NUM_TARJETA || ' ' || filas.FECHA || ' ' || filas.IMPORTE || ' ' || filas.PUNTOSCOMP || ' ' || filas.TIENDA);
    END LOOP;
END IF;

CLOSE cursorDNI;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Esa tarjeta no está asociada a ese DNI.');
END;
```

Lo que me interesa es que cuando pongo una tarjeta en la que su propietario no sea el del DNI, me salte la excepción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%NOTFOUND` y `%FOUND` toman se valor del `FETCH` mas reciente; En los cursores explícitos necesitas hacer `FETCH`.

```
OPEN cursorDNI;
FETCH cursorDNI INTO v_DNI;
IF cursorDNI%NOTFOUND THEN
```

Comment: Llevas toda la razón, era eso lo que faltaba!

Muchas gracias